# Procedure não retorna a coluna completa

Tags: sql, select, firebird

Criei uma procedure com o ibexpert, faz o *commit* corretamente, mas na hora de rodar a *procedure*, recebo o erro:

> multiple rows in singleton select.

A minha intenção é listar todos os valores da coluna cidade da tabela destino. Quando executo o *select* numa *query* normal, ele retorna todos os valores da coluna, só não faz o mesmo na *procedure*, sendo que estou executando da mesma forma.

Segue abaixo o código:

```
create or alter procedure VER_TODOS_DEST  
returns (CIDADES char(20))  
as  
begin  
  select cidade from destino  
  into :cidades;  
  suspend;  
end
```

Comment: o into :cidades  não significa que você está jogando o valor na variável? sendo assim você não pode colocar mais de 1 linha em um variável, retire a linha into e teste.

Answer (score 0):

Dentro de uma `procedure` ou `trigger` o comando `select` só pode retornar 1 registro.

Para fazer o que deseja precisa usar o `for select` como abaixo.

```
create or alter procedure VER_TODOS_DEST
returns (
    CIDADES char(20))
as
begin
  for
      select
          CIDADE
      from
          DESTINO
      into
          :CIDADES
  do
    suspend;
end
```

Comment: @Fabrício Gustavo Se a resposta lhe foi útil, se puder marque-a como aceita `√`, assim quando outros usuários visualizarem sua questão verão que já tem uma resposta correta e aceita por você.